# Python Dependency management practices

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

Now I'm taking part in node.js project and i like "node way" of dependecy management.

I'll provide some examples for those who haven't worked with `npm`

- `npm install package_name --save` - installs `package_name` as **production** dependency
- `npm install package name --save-dev` - install `package_name` as development dependecy.

All deps are stored in `package.json` file, which is indexed by version control system. When i clone repo, i just type `npm install` in terminal and it installs everything.
As far as i know, `pip freeze` is able to do it, but:

On production server I can type `npm install --production` and all my build tools, testing frameworks, etc. are not installed. Just production deps.

So, the question is:

How do you split production and development dependecies with pip(or other tool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice solution, it is quite new tool, called [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv). Seems an analog of npm for python.

Answer (score 4):

I would create two [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) ([venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for Python 3) with a separate `requirements.txt` file for each, like `requirements-production.txt` and `requirements-develop.txt`, but that looks a bit strange to me.

Personally, I usually use git's branches to separate production/development code.  Most of the development goes in the `develop` branch, there's a single `requirements.txt` (which can change over time, for sure). When everything's alright and/or the development cycle has ended, I just merge it with the `master` branch.  Haven't had a need to test different versions of dependencies simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you very much, don't you think it needs too much manual work?

Comment: @AlexeySidash Nah, it's pretty easy and fast, at least to me :) I also deploy projects using [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org), so it's even faster - actually, just a command: `fab deploy -R production`. It connects to the production servers by ssh, does `git pull` from the corresponding branch (`master`) and restarts whatever's in charge on the server (like uwsgi).

Comment: Thanks for fabric. It looks nice!